# Defining the transaction object for offline transaction signing using "web3.js from the broswer"

Tags: solidity, web3js

I am trying to call a contract method ( a write operation ) and sign the transaction manually using my privatekey. The transaction hash is being generated but when I go to etherscan, the transaction shows failed. My web3.js code is as follows.

```
 var tx = new ethereumjs.Tx({
                from: '0x3dCDe57Ad49d639c4D702b607Dd5eBc0aB54A671',
                nonce: web3.toHex(txCount),
                gasLimit: web3.toHex(1000000),
                gasPrice: web3.toHex(web3.toWei('10', 'gwei')),
                data: contractInstance.incrementTest.getData(10).
            });
```

I have doubt in the data part of the transaction object. Is this the correct way to use it? incrementTest is the contract method and 10 is the parameter i wish to pass to incrementTest.

Error displayed in etherscan : Warning! Error Encounter during Contract Execution [stack underflow (0 <=> 15)

the error is different for different contract methods ie; when i change the data value in the transaction object.

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
data: contractInstance.methods.incrementTest(10).encodeABI()
```